# How to merge object TargetGroupARNs and TargetGroupArn unique in bash shell?

Tags: json, linux, bash, shell

I have two json files.

I wanna merge objects in targetgroup.json and autoscaling.json with TargetGroupARNs and TargetGroupArn unique value in bash shell.

I am using jq version 1.4 and unable upgrade to last version because some cause.

```
#cat autoscaling.json
      {
        "AutoScalingGroups": [
            {
                "AutoScalingGroupARN": "arn:aws:autoscaling:ap-northeast-1:050073205187:autoScalingGroup:29f22791-b9cf-49c2-9ba6-b9ac2759d767:autoScalingGroupName/asg-dev-srv-01-20190327_133322",
                "ServiceLinkedRoleARN": "arn:aws:iam::050073205187:role/aws-service-role/autoscaling.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAutoScaling",
                "TargetGroupARNs": [
                    "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ap-northeast-1:050073205187:targetgroup/dev-trial-tg/ef79ad5c9df9014e"
                ]

            },
            {
                "AutoScalingGroupARN": "arn:aws:autoscaling:ap-northeast-1:050073205187:autoScalingGroup:cf662dc3-4e27-4022-a165-ebba8ca9488b:autoScalingGroupName/asg_group",
                "ServiceLinkedRoleARN": "arn:aws:iam::050073205187:role/aws-service-role/autoscaling.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAutoScaling",
                "TargetGroupARNs": [
                    "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ap-northeast-1:050073205187:targetgroup/dev-trial1-tg/580ab71538a59063"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }


 #cat targetgroup.json
[
  {
    "TargetGroupArn": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ap-northeast-1:050073205187:targetgroup/dev-trial-tg/ef79ad5c9df9014e",
    "TargetGroupName": "dev-trial-tg"
  },
  {
    "TargetGroupArn": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ap-northeast-1:050073205187:targetgroup/dev-trial1-tg/580ab71538a59063",
    "TargetGroupName": "dev-trial1-tg"
  }
]
```

My desired is:

```
[
    {
        "AutoScalingGroups": [
            {
                "AutoScalingGroupARN": "arn:aws:autoscaling:ap-northeast-1:050073205187:autoScalingGroup:29f22791-b9cf-49c2-9ba6-b9ac2759d767:autoScalingGroupName/asg-dev-srv-01-20190327_133322",
                "ServiceLinkedRoleARN": "arn:aws:iam::050073205187:role/aws-service-role/autoscaling.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAutoScaling",
                "TargetGroupARNs": [
                    "TargetGroupArn": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ap-northeast-1:050073205187:targetgroup/dev-trial-tg/ef79ad5c9df9014e",
                    "TargetGroupName": "dev-trial-tg"
                ],
            },
            {
                "AutoScalingGroupARN": "arn:aws:autoscaling:ap-northeast-1:050073205187:autoScalingGroup:cf662dc3-4e27-4022-a165-ebba8ca9488b:autoScalingGroupName/asg_group",
                "ServiceLinkedRoleARN": "arn:aws:iam::050073205187:role/aws-service-role/autoscaling.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAutoScaling",
                "TargetGroupARNs": [
                    "TargetGroupArn": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ap-northeast-1:050073205187:targetgroup/dev-trial1-tg/580ab71538a59063",
                    "TargetGroupName": "dev-trial1-tg"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I tried, but it was too hard for me. I hope you can help me.

Comment: Your desired output is not valid JSON

Comment: @oguzismail can you help me? :(

Comment: Is this what you want? `jq -n 'input | reduce (input|to_entries)[] as $p (.; .AutoScalingGroups[$p.key].TargetGroupARNs = $p.value)' autoscaling.json targetgroup.json`

Comment: @oguzismail. It's work. Thank so much bro

Comment: @oguzismail sorry for this feedback. I see your solution only works for jq version 1.5. I tried using jq version 1.4 and reported an error and did not work.
Hope you can help me.

Comment: latest version of jq is 1.6, you better upgrade it

Comment: @oguzismail Because my company policy, I unable upgrade to the latest version :(

Comment: Well, I got versions 1.5 and 1.6 installed on my machines, so I can't help you. Sorry

Comment: @oguzismail oh. thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

This is solution from @oguzismail

```
jq -n 'input | reduce (input|to_entries)[] as $p (.; .AutoScalingGroups[$p.key].TargetGroupARNs = $p.value)' autoscaling.json targetgroup.json
```